# Proof - Inverse Permutation

Tags: proof-writing, permutations, permutation-cycles

How can one prove that for every permutation $l: [r] ↦ [r]$  there is $n \in\mathbb{N}$  so  $l^n=l^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Give us some more information, please. For example, you could show that the set of all permutations on $[r] \mapsto [r]$ can be treated as a group where the operation is composition of functions. Then, use the mechanics of group theory to prove it, as you wind up with the Symmetric group $S_r$. Since it is a finite group, the property you seek is obvious. However, if you are not looking for an approach using group theory (as it does not seem that you are), then we would need some more information on what type of proof you are looking for.

Comment: One might consider the fact the permutations are bijections from $X$ to $X$.

Comment: Interesting; Bijectinos are indeed inversable, but how can I ues that with the composition of permutations?

Comment: Consider the infinite list $l, l^2, l^3, \ldots$.  There are only finitely many permutations.

Comment: @OryD Let $S_r$ be the set of bijections from $[r] \to [r]$. Define $e:[r] \to [r]$ to be $e(n) = n$. This is clearly a bijection, so $e \in S_r$. We say $e$ is the identity element of $S_r$. For all elements of $S_r$, since they are bijections, they have an inverse. Thus for all $\pi \in S_r$, you have $\pi \circ \pi^{-1}(n) = \pi^{-1}(n)\circ \pi(n) = e(n) = n$. Finally, prove that composition of functions is associative. Then, you have a group. Once you have a group, use group theory to prove the claim.

Comment: The proof would look something like this: There are a finite number of bijections from $[r] \mapsto [r]$. Therefore, (as Randall said) the infinite list $l,l^2,l^3,\cdots$ is a finite list. If $l=e$, then you are done, as $e^1 = e^{-1}$. So, assume $l\neq e$. Then there must exist $n_1> n_2$ such that $l^{n_1} = l^{n_2}$. But then, $l^{n_1-n_2} = l^{n_1}\circ l^{-n_2} = l^{n_2}\circ l^{-n_2} = e$. Now, compose $l^{-1}$ on both sides to get: $l^{n_1-n_2-1} = l^{-1}$.